# How to replace animation state or copy transition from one state to another

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, animator

I am using unity animator window where i have different states connected to each other and after a long time i am able to set it transition. Now i want to replace one animation state with another animation state (Means different animation object). There should be two ways 
1. either i replaced my current state with antoher animation
2. i bring the new animation into animator and copy transition link on it.

But sadly i don't how to do both because neither i know how to replace nor i am able to copy the transition link? The long step which i know that i make every transition again which is seriously time consuming. Do you guys know anyway?

Comment: Can't you just replace the Animation clip (`Motion` field when you click on the state)?

Comment: Yes, I have done that and its worked. Although i have identified it myself but your comment can be the answer.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan you can leave an answer here of how you solved it, in case other people run into the same issue.

Comment: i think that @Hellium should add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to replace the animation clip in the `Motion` field, visible in the inspector when you select the desired state.

You can also rename the state using the top-most input field in the inspector (*Grounded* in the image below)

[image: StateBehaviour]

Comment: Thanks, i am waiting for your answer.